# Prove $0 \lt \int_0^1 f(x)\sin(rx)\mathrm{d} x \le \frac{1}{n!}, r\in(0, \pi] $, $f(x) = \frac{x^n(1-x)^n}{n!}, x\in [0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I'm trying to demonstrate that $\pi$ is irrational and at a point in the proof it is asked to prove that

$0 \lt \int_0^1 f(x)\sin(rx)\mathrm{d} x \le \frac{1}{n!}, r\in(0, \pi] $

where $f(x) = \frac{x^n(1-x)^n}{n!}, x\in [0, 1]$

I have thought that since $ 0 \le x \le 1 $ it must be that $ 0 \le x(1 - x) \lt 1 $ and so $ 0 \le f(x) \lt \frac{1}{n!}$ and also $-1 \le \sin(rx) \le 1$

but I'm not sure if they are sufficient conditions for the integral to be bounded.

Comment: The upper bound will work that way (actually, you can even get a $1/4^n$ in there, since $x(1-x) \leq 1/4$ for all $x\in[0,1]$). You also have to prove the integral is positive (strictly), however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f(x)$ is symmetric about $x = 1/2$ and that at $x = 1/2$ the value is $1/4$. It is straightforward to see that this is a maximum and so $\displaystyle \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \vert f(x) \vert = 1/4$. You also noted that $\displaystyle \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \vert \sin(rx) \vert \leq 1$. Then, 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f(x)\sin(rx)dx &\leq \left\vert \int_0^1 f(x)\sin(rx)dx \right\vert \leq \int_0^1 \vert f(x) \sin(rx) dx\vert \leq \int_0^1 \vert f(x) \vert \cdot \vert\sin(rx)\vert dx\\
&\leq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{4n!} \cdot 1dx = \frac{1}{4n!}
\end{align*}

The integral is clearly positive since both $f(x)$ and $\sin(rx)$ are positive on $(0,1)$ for $r \in (0,\pi]$.